# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 while inserting into remote MONGODB

Tags: android, mongodb

```js
04-06 13:29:26.403 16654-17357/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                   Process: com.donateblood.blooddonation, PID: 16654
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads
                                                       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:946)
                                                       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:969)
                                                       at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:829)
                                                       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:572)
                                                       at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:156)
                                                       at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:149)
                                                       at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:15994)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:3675)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.drawableStateChanged(AppCompatButton.java:143)
                                                       at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:16023)
                                                       at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:6723)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1457)
                                                       at com.donateblood.blooddonation.SignupActivity.onSignupSuccess(SignupActivity.java:81)
                                                       at com.donateblood.blooddonation.SignupActivity.addUsertoDB(SignupActivity.java:183)
                                                       at com.donateblood.blooddonation.SignupActivity$dbAsync.doInBackground(SignupActivity.java:152)
                                                       at com.donateblood.blooddonation.SignupActivity$dbAsync.doInBackground(SignupActivity.java:137)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
```

```html
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;

/**
 * Created by YouCaf Iqbal on 4/5/2016.
 */
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";
    DBCollection collection;
    DB db;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_signup) Button _signupButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.link_login) TextView _loginLink;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_location) TextView _locText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_number) TextView _numText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Spinner spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.blood_type);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);


        _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signup();
            }
        });

        _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void signup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

        if (validate()==false) {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;
        }

        _signupButton.setEnabled(false);
        dbAsync addtobd = new dbAsync();
        addtobd.execute();
    }

    public void onSignupSuccess() {

        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();
    }

    public void onSignupFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sign Up failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;
        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
        String location = _locText.getText().toString();
        String number = _numText.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
            _nameText.setError("at least 3 characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _nameText.setError(null);
        }

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        if (location.isEmpty()) {
            _locText.setError("Enter location");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _locText.setError(null);
        }
        if (number.isEmpty()) {
            _numText.setError("Enter valid number");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _numText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }

    public class dbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Account");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            addUsertoDB();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void addUsertoDB(){
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://yousaf:UC1941994@ds015730.mlab.com:15730/donateblood");
        MongoClient client = null;
        client = new MongoClient(uri);
        db = client.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
        String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
        String location = _locText.getText().toString();
        String number = _numText.getText().toString();
        collection = db.getCollection("UserDetails");
        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("Name", name);
        document.put("email", email);
        document.put("password", password);
        document.put("location", location);
        document.put("number", number);
        collection.insert(document);
        onSignupSuccess();
    }
}
```

When i click on create account the progress bar shows creating account and then after sometime "unfortunately app stopped working" message come and it stops but the values are added to the database successfully.

Comment: Connecting your app directly to a database is not a very wise idea. There are security considerations, the fact that database connections to clients come with quite a large memory cost per connection, and a whole host of things, including but not limited to maintaining stateful connections over unreliable networks applicable to a mobile application is just a pain. Before even more problems rear their head, construct something like a RESTful interface to actually do all the talking to the database instead, and just have your "app" interact with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting  `onSignupSuccess()` in `onPostExecute()`

**EDIT**

You are trying to modify your UI in a thread which is not the UIThread and this causing your error, `doInBackground()` calls `addUsertoDB()` which calls
`onSignupSuccess();` which is modifing the UI, call `onSignupSuccess();` in the UIThread

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11911669)

Comment: Is it more useful right now, or you need more info to know where the error was?

Comment: Now it makes sense :)